# Drip tray for flower pot on top of 55 gal plastic rain barrel

Tags: outdoor

I have a DIY 55 gallon plastic rain barrel, one of these:
[image: Text]
and would like to put a flower pot on top of it. I'm now looking for a sturdy solution to attach a drip tray to the top barrel. I have a nice wide clay pot, but it's pretty heavy and I don't want it to damage the barrel.
I could of course, build a wooden enclosure, but perhaps there's an easier solution –
I was thinking some kind of clamps that attach to the rim, and hold a plate on which the drip tray sits.
Any ideas or examples you might have come across how to do that?